# Take A Partial Screenshot on Android?

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to save off a Bitmap of the current screen for my users to share, but I only want to do a partial (I want to remove the areas that have user buttons and such).

I have found code on taking a full screenshot, but cannot figure out how to do this.

Hoping there is something easy that I am just missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the partial area of which the screenshot is to be taken in a `ViewGRoup` say `RelativeLayout`. Then when you launch the `Activity` just make sure to build the drawing cache as follows

```
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        relativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        relativeLayout.buildDrawingCache();
```

And then when you actually want ot take the screenshot of that particular area, just get the Screenshot in the form of a `Bitmap` from the drawing cache

```
bitmap = relativeLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Partial area is already set like that, so perfect. Thank you. I figured I was just missing. it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can place elements in Frame Layout which you want to in screen shot.
Then you can take screen shot of Frame layout.

You can refer this Link : http://divyamotiwala.blogspot.in/2013/10/taking-screenshot-of-layout-in-android.html